# What is the difference between aluminum tape and speed tape?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aircraft-maintenance

What is the difference between aluminum tape and Speed tape? Are these same or not?

Answer (score 3):

Speed tape is aluminum tape that is much thicker with stronger adhesive than the aluminum tape you get at Home Depot, that is approved for temporary application on external surfaces of airplanes.